# convert big data into column list in r

Tags: r

i know there have been many solutions here concerning the conversion of data-frame to list etc but i'm really struggling to a problem. i hope i can get some help.
my data is as follow:

```
            car  bus   train plane bike ship ferry
1977-02-15 4.63 4.85   5.09 6.04 6.35 6.72  7.36  7.70
1977-02-16 4.62 4.82   5.06 6.02 6.32 6.70  7.34  7.67
1977-02-17 4.61 4.80   5.04 5.99 6.29 6.67  7.26  7.67
1977-02-18 4.66 4.86   5.12 6.06 6.40 6.82  7.41  7.76
1977-02-22 4.69 4.89   5.15 6.09 6.43 6.84  7.42  7.77
1977-02-23 4.70 4.92   5.21 6.12 6.51 6.95  7.48  7.81
```

i want to convert into this(column list):

```
4.63
4.85
5.09
6.04
.
.
.
4.62
4.82
```

i really hope to get some help from you guys. i already tried splits,unlist functions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried, as well as give some more context about the problem.  Are you trying to read data from a text file, or is it in a particular data structure?

Comment: Please post `str(my_data)` where "mydata" is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can transpose the dataset, concatenate (`c`) to a `vector` and create a `data.frame` with a single column (assuming that the 'date' is the row names)

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c(t(df1)))
```